# ExtJS quick start - how to run

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I've started to learn Ext JS and immediately stumbled on the 1st step of [their quick start](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/quick_start/introduction.html).

Where should I put that hello world code to see the result in my web page, not their interactive demo?

I have local web server up and running, so the question is in application's files layout.

Comment: For a project you should use Sencha Cmd to create an application, if possible. You will find everything you need, including a sample application with store, view etc., in the application working directory you provided to the Sencha Cmd command line utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an `app.js` file in the root of your project, and then put the code there. You also should include this file in the `index.html` file, after the inclusion of library scripts, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Basically you firstly load the ExtJS library files, and then you load a file that does something using ExtJS.

Or you might not need any additional file, just include the code in `index.html` (also after the library is loaded) in form of inline javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'New Panel',
            html: 'My new panel!'
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: Ext.Viewport.add is not a function` when I include `app.js` in the `index.html` file.

Comment: And if I include `ext-modern-all-debug.js` instead of `ext-all-debug.js` I get `TypeError: Ext.Viewport is undefined`.

Comment: And if I follow an example from ExtJS documentation (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.Viewport.html) I get `TypeError: Ext.setup is not a function`. What a mess.

Comment: Ah. Finally they got it right in the final version of docs (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.Viewport.html). It works with ExtJS 6.2.0 GPL even though the doc is written for ExtJS 6.5.1.